# Javascript: Removing first text line if string starts with certain characters

Tags: javascript

I wrote a script for some text manipulation, and want to add a function so that the first line of my input string is removed if it starts with the symbol '>'. I tried to find a solution for hours now, but I cannot get it to work: Somehow the first line is not removed properly.

My input text  should be processed as it is if it looks like this:
"`HABHHIKKLLMMNMNIL`"
and the first line should be removed if it looks like this:
"

```
>some text
HABHHIKKLLMMNMNIL
```

"

My current solution would look like this:

```
// remove first line if starts with '>'


if (sequence_str.substring(0) === '>'){
    // break the textblock into an array of lines
    var lines = sequence_str.split('\n');
    // remove one line, starting at the first position
    lines.splice(0,1);
    // join the array back into a single string
    var sequence_str = lines.join('\n');
}

sequence_str = sequence_str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); //remove linebreaks
```

I would appreciate any ideas, and I hope some could help me to figure out where the problem is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
sequence_str = sequence_str.replace(/^>.*/,'');
```

This will remove the first line if it starts with `>`. It will leave an empty line (the newline character is unaffected), but since you're later stripping all line-breaks, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you, sounds reasonable. However, I tried this before and it didn't work. Now, after I tried it again, it sill won't work. This is really strange. edit: i figured out that the problem is the if condition, for whatever reason it doest not recognize the ">"

Comment: Found my error, see my answer below (I created a separate answer so the syntax is easier to read)

Answer (score 0):

just try this

"lines = lines.splice(0,1);"

instead of "lines.splice(0,1);"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, I really like the short codes you suggested.

The error was that I used

```
if (sequence_str.substring(0) === '>')
```

where it should be

```
if (sequence_str.substring(0,1) === '>')
```

I am a JavaScript beginner and come from the Python corner, please excuse my stupid mistake

EDIT:
If someone is interested to see how the end product looks like:
http://bluewoodtree.zxq.net/crop_and_cleave.html

Comment: You could use `charAt(0)` - I think that's what you were confusing it with ;)

Comment: Thanks, that's an even prettier solution! In python I was used to write it like this: if string[0] == ">":